# Distance Matrix - ValueError: array is too big

Tags: python, dataframe, distance-matrix

So I have a dataframe **df** that is basically a list of id's and coordinates and I want to get the distance matrix out of it.
The code was working fine until i created a bigger **df** with the size of (337644, 2)
note: using 64-bit machine with 32GB RAM

**df2** is the distance matrix where the error shows up

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_coordinates_int, columns=['xcord', 'ycord'], index=list_id)
df2= pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix(df.values, df.values), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

i got the following error:

result = np.empty((m,n),dtype=float)  # FIXME: figure out the best dtype

ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.

my RAM is not fully consumed while running the code so i'm not sure what's the problem here.

Comment: the Memory issue is solved by using more RAM for the code.
however, another issue showed up which is ValueError, saying that the resutled array is larger than the possible size.

Comment: could be API side limits ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits

Comment: I'm not using any related google maps.
I simply have very large id's and coordinates files